# Registering a generic type with a generic argument in Simple Injector

Tags: generics, types, simple-injector, registering

I want to register several interfaces having a generic argument. This is an example of the code:

```cs
container.Register(
    typeof(IDataMerger<OriginalObject, Response<MergeObjectA>>), 
    typeof(DataMerger<MergeObjectA>));
```

What is the best way to do this other than making a new registration for each merge object?

I have made attempts using code similar to the code below, but I am receiving an error.

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IDataMerger<,>),
    typeof(DataMerger<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(ConsumerObject<,>)
        .GetGenericArguments()[1]), 
    c => c.Consumer?.ImplementationType != null
        && c.Consumer.ImplementationType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
        && c.Consumer.ImplementationType
              .GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(OriginalObject));
```

Any help that you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#registration-of-open-generic-types) shows examples that show how to do this.

Assuming the following definitions:

```cs
interface IDataMerger<TRequest, TResponse> { }

class DataMerger<T> : IDataMerger<OriginalObject, Response<T>> { }
```

you can make the following registration:

```cs
container.Register(typeof(IDataMerger<,>), typeof(DataMerger<>));
```

Comment: This solution is valid for a parameter that is a non-generic parameter. I could not seem to find a solution for a generic parameter, so I changed it to a non-generic parameter. Thanks.